# How can I load image from my pc through html?

Tags: html

My HTML files are inside "HTML Folder" there is a subfolder name called"Photo_folder" which holds my images.

So I have written the path

`<img src="file://E:/Html%20Folder/Photo_folder/myphoto.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Photo">`

The image is not loading on the page.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us your code please? Just edit your question and we'll be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative path:

```
./Photo_folder/myphoto.jpg
```